# ACPI Error: No handler or method for GPE 21, disabling event (20181213/evgpe-835)

Tags: boot, acpi

I have a Ubuntu KDE Neon 5.16 system Plasma Version: 5.16.5 Kernel Version 5.0.0-27-generic. It works great about 80% of the time, but seemingly randomly on boot I will get a endless loading screen (KDE splash), dropping to terminal I get a very fast logging of `ACPI Error: No handler or method for GPE 21, disabling event (20181213/evgpe-835)` with the "21" number increasing 1 on each log. This just keeps logging to the screen forever. I have to force shutdown holding the power button. Given a few chances to boot it will get past this and then the system is stable. The only thing I try is removing all usb / external screens and this may help (not certain of this yet). Any known issues or ways to troubleshoot this, I can work with restarting, but I would hate for it to start happening more often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: 
Try kernel bootparameter:

```
pci=nommconf
```

Full version:

I had the same very nasty problem with ACPI,

On boot the kernel basically spamming:

```
kernel: [   26.237796] ACPI Error: No handler or method for GPE 08,
```

Kernel bootparameter: acpi=off made the system bootable, but the laptop basically unusable (no touchpad, no cpu throttling, nvidia could not initialize etc etc.)

After much agony I found that it was described here very recently (hopefully patched soon):   https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=203617

Which suggested using: `pci=nommconf`

which solved my problem for now.  I have so far not found any serious drawback so I'm happy.

Comment: Great info, for me it actually (seems to have, fingers crossed) resolved itself, have not had this issue in awhile.